# Creating an index after dropping gives message index already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having an issue dropping and creating the index in sql server 2008 r2. When I create an index after dropping it says index already exists. If I search the index table i dont see it exist

Get the following error message

> Msg 1913, Level 16, State 1, Line 40 The operation failed because an
>   index or statistics with name 'IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId' already
>   exists on table 'CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesIpoData'.

Tried the following

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM  sys.indexes ind INNER JOIN   sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
where ind.name = 'IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId')
    DROP INDEX IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId ON PartiesIpoData
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId on CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesIpoData(companyId)
```

And this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesIpoData'))
    DROP INDEX IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId ON PartiesIpoData
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId on CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesIpoData(companyId)
```

This is how the index table looks like

[image]

Index table

Comment: Did you try refreshing the table in SSMS?  This sounds like maybe something is operating on stale information.

Comment: If it run just the If condtion part where it drops and refresh SSMS, I still see the index on the table. So evenrtually it is not dropping the index on the table

Comment: you can use `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);` in your create index statement

Answer (score 0):

Just search the existing name Index by SQL Server query :

```
SELECT * FROM Sys.Indexes WHERE name LIKE '%%'
```

If same name index already exist,then drop it.